# How to catch an animation end in deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I was wondering if there is any possibility to catch if animation fired during deleteRowsAtIndexPaths did end? What I am trying to do is removing some all rows from UITableView except one that i tapped. Next I want to insert few rows into the same UITableView. Both operations are performed in separates beginUpadate/endUpdate blocks. The problem is that before deleting animation ends, the inserting animation starts and I want it be fired one after another because inserted rows are coming from external webservice.

I was thinking about wrapping inserting and deleting methods (in UITableView subclass) in methods where I could replace standard animation with custom ones and use objective-c blocks to fire one after another when the first ends but it appears to be imposible or I just can't do it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe that wrapping your table update in `animateWithDuration` would work:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
    [coursesTable beginUpdates];
    …
    [coursesTable endUpdates];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Code to run when table updates are complete.
}];
```

Other methods that I found suggested here on Stack Overflow did not work for me.

I used this technique at one time and tested it enough to verify that the completion block was called after I called the table's endUpdates method and the time that it was called seemed reasonable, but I rewrote my code so I didn't need it any more before I had completely verified that the animation was actually finished.

Answer (score 0):

use `CATransaction` to catch any animation's completion

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
     // completion
})
// do your animation here
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 11 to above:

```
[tblProducts performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self->tblProducts deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.animDeleteIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self->tblProducts reloadData];
}];
```